# Subdomains in Nuxt 3 Router / middleware

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Been trying a few options now without success.

I am basically trying to recreate the system that NextJS has in place for their [Platforms Kit](https://github.com/vercel/platforms).

Basically I want to be able to have two pages folders - one for the app (dashboard, creating posts etc) and one for the blogs (users posts, frontfacing blog site)

I want to allow both subdomains and custom domains.
So
`app.root.com` -> `pages/app`
`subdomain.root.com` -> `pages/blog`
`custom.com` -> `pages/blog`

I have set everything up DNS wise to make this work, but just need the router options. There is a Nuxt 2 solution here, but it doesnt work for nuxt 3: https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module/issues/22#issuecomment-628313757

Thanks!
Nicolaj

Answer (score 0):

Keypress is built with Nuxt, inspired by the Vercel platforms kit.
https://github.com/zernonia/keypress

It uses the ssrContext to get the subdomain.

```
const { ssrContext } = useNuxtApp()
ssrContext?.event.context.subdomain
```

See:
https://github.com/zernonia/keypress/blob/main/server/middleware/subdomain.ts
https://github.com/zernonia/keypress/blob/main/app/router.options.ts